# Jump to next identifier in Vim help files

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions, help-system, plugin-unimpaired

I regularly find myself in the situation that I am reading a help topic and see an identifier (the blue underlined words) that I want to follow with `<C-]>`. However, most of the time the identifier is not (yet) under my cursor.

Instead of searching for the identifier with `/part_of_identifier<CR>` I would like to use a smarter variant, a [unimpaired-like](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) mapping like `]i` to go to the next available identifier after my cursor (and `[i` to go to the previous identifier).

How could I create such a mapping? Or is there a builtin command already for that? If not, do you see an alternative/smarter way how I could navigate identifiers inside Vim help files? Or can I tag all Vim's and the plugins' help files with ctags and use `]t` somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the help files the identifiers are actually marked as `|identifier|` (but you don't see the `|` because of the syntax file, use `set ft=txt` in an help buffer to check what I'm talking about).

You could then create a mapping which would look for the next pattern `\|\W*\|` and you should be good.

Something like:

```
execute "nnoremap ]i :call search('\\|\\w*\\|')<CR>"
```

(The execute and multi `\\|` are here to deal with the escaping problems)

**Edit** @EvergreenTree came up with a much more elegant solution:

```
nnoremap ]i :call search('\v\\|.{-}\\|')<CR>
```

---

It is also possible to use the same method to jump to the help topics (the string used in the commands `:h foo`) which are delimited by `*` characters:

```
nnoremap ]i :call search('*\w*\*')<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it does not do what I want, cause I used the wrong term in my problem description (sorry for that). I want the mapping to jump to the next *Link* to an identifier, so I can then press `<C-]>`. So it would be nice if you could update the solution to use `|` instead of `*` :-)

Comment: Does my update is what you were looking for? :-)

Comment: At the moment not yet: If I open help files, e.g. `:h help` and press `]i`, then the cursor doesn't move (I expect it to jump to the blue underlined word `help-translated`).

Comment: Yup because of the escaping of `|` let me work on that

Comment: `\W` is the wrong atom to use in this case, since it matches all non-word characters.  Use `.` instead.  Also, using a greedy multi like `*` means no more than one match will be found for each line.  Use `{-}` instead.  Put together: `'\v\|.{-}\|'`.  The reason for `\v` is that patterns can be interpreted differently depending on the `magic` option, and `\v` explicitly sets it to "very magic".

Comment: @EvergreenTree: Yup good suggestions thanks.

Comment: See the edit with the solution suggested by evergreenTree, it works fine for me.

Comment: Perfect, it works now :) Thanks statox and EvergreenTree!

Comment: Also note that you can create a backwards searching version by passing `'b'` as an argument to `search()`.

Answer (score 5):

This is [what I use](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.vim/ftplugin/help/navigate.vim).

As well as `|.....|` tags, it will also stop on options of the form `'.....'`

But it's not pretty...

```
### ~/.vim/ftplugin/help/navigate.vim ###
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]i /\('\zs\k\+'\\|[<Bar>]\zs\k\+[<Bar>]\)<CR>:set nohlsearch<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [i ?\('\zs\k\+'\\|[<Bar>]\zs\k\+[<Bar>]\)<CR>:set nohlsearch<CR>
```

We use `<zs>` to land the cursor on the start of the word, rather than on the `|` or `'` character.

Comment: I have changed the keybind LHS to suit you.

Comment: Your solution works great, too :) I must have messed something up when pasting your code in my `.vimrc` and having changed the `<Tab>` to `]i`, because I tried your code then and it didn't work for me. It does work now and you didn't change anything other than the mapped keys, so I messed that up before. You deserve credit here too :)

Answer (score 1):

Similar to joeytwiddle's answer:

```
### ~/.vim/ftplugin/help/navigate.vim ###
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> [i ?\('\zs[a-z]\{2,\}'\\|'\zst_..'\\|[<Bar>]\zs\k\+[<Bar>]\)<CR>:noh<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ]i /\('\zs[a-z]\{2,\}'\\|'\zst_..'\\|[<Bar>]\zs\k\+[<Bar>]\)<CR>:noh<CR>
```

Two changes:

1. The branch finding option tags (those of the form `'...'`) changed to vim's [help option syntax](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/c136a3528b7ebb825c3863d701af44f023381181/runtime/syntax/help.vim#L45-L46) exactly. (That link is fixed to latest commit on master, at the time of this writing, but since it was last changed [17 years ago](https://github.com/vim/vim/blame/c136a3528b7ebb825c3863d701af44f023381181/runtime/syntax/help.vim#L45-L46), it's probably safe for a while.)
2. `:set nohlsearch` changed to `:noh`, in case you usually have `hlsearch` on (I do).