# Read values from a highlight group

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

I can read a value from an option like:

```
let b = &background
```

Is there a way to read a value from a highlight group? Something like this pseudo-code:

```
let b = &StatusLine['ctermbg']
```

Ultimately, what I want to do is define a new highlight group in terms of other highlight group colors (not a link, but picking specific values from more than one highlight group, namely `StatusLine` and `StatusLineNC` in my case)

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20753/getting-an-rgb-color-from-highlight-group

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, there's not a simple way to do this. Here's a function that should be able to return the value given the highlight group and term. If there is no such term, an empty string will be returned instead.

```
function! ReturnHighlightTerm(group, term)
   " Store output of group to variable
   let output = execute('hi ' . a:group)

   " Find the term we're looking for
   return matchstr(output, a:term.'=\zs\S*')
endfunction
```

Given this function you should be able to do

```
let b = ReturnHighlightTerm('StatusLine', 'ctermbg')
```

to get what you want.

See [`:help execute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29), [`:help :highlight`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight), and [`:help matchstr()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchstr%28%29) for more info on how this works.

Comment: Using the `execute()` function is better than `:redir`, e.g. `let l:output = execute('hi ' . a:group)`. See [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12202/51) for a very similar example with `:syntax list`. Aside from being more readable, I've found that `redir` has some serious issues in some cases. I forgot what it was *exactly* since it was a while ago, but I believe it had to do with nesting two `redirs` in some complicated ways with plugins/autocommands which causes the wrong output to end up in the wrong variable (!!!!) Suffice to say, I haven't used `redir` since.

Comment: Ah, cool! I didn't know about `execute()`. Thanks!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I believe that problem is not solved by using execute(). I think execute() suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Ow, I didn't know that @ChristianBrabandt :-( I haven't had any problems since I replaced redir with execute(), though; but perhaps that's just coincidence.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker @ChristianBrabandt at least the `execute()` solution is simpler and reads better, so I'd stick with it...

Comment: Why prepending with `a:`?

Comment: @job_start `a:` is an argument variable. It's required to reference the passed in variables.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up writing a generic function that turns a highlight group into a dictionary of `{key}={arg}` pairs. Leaving it here for future reference:

```
function! GetHighlight(group)
  let output = execute('hi ' . a:group)
  let list = split(output, '\s\+')
  let dict = {}
  for item in list
    if match(item, '=') > 0
      let splited = split(item, '=')
      let dict[splited[0]] = splited[1]
    endif
  endfor
  return dict
endfunction
```