# Get immediate feedback about a search string with no matches in vim

Tags: search, highlight

Is there a way to immediately get feedback about a search string with no matches?

At the moment I have to press Enter first to get `Pattern not found`. I'd like if the background (of the search line or of vim itself) turned red the moment there are no matches anymore.

The scenario that bugs me is the following: I type `/` and start entering a complicated string/regexp.  Since I have `set incsearch` the screen starts jumping around until at some point it settles. At this point I have to scan my entire screen to see if something was found or not. This takes a while even with `set hlsearch`. I have attached a screen recording of an example where a search string doesn't give any results because of a typo (entering 5 instead of 6) but it takes me a second or so to realize that typo. Then I fix the search and it again takes me a second or so to realize that I did find something this time.

https://streamable.com/v5w31

Comment: I would expect it to be relatively clear with highlight search when it fails: there’s no highlights, even at a quick glance.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble did you check the video? I don't find the highlights very clear, depending on the syntax highlighting.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. Perhaps this [issue 453](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/453) would solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a vimscript solution which seems to work (at least according to my quick tests). This is a workaround and it clearly has a lot of place for improvements.

- It changes the color of the status line using the `:highlight` command so obviously you need to have `set laststatus=2`.
- It uses some global variables, theirs scope could be limited and I think they could even be eliminated.
- It also uses the autocommand events `CmdlineEnter` and `CmdlineLeave` which are included only in recent vim version.
- I haven't tested the code with complex searches I don't know how well it behaves with complex regexes and escaped characters.

Anyway the idea was mainly to create a proof of concept, not a complete feature.

Add this to your `vimrc` (actually you should put the function in an autoload directory but that's not the point of the question):

```
function! HighlightSearch(timer)
    " When it is the first call to the function we save the current status of
    " the StatusLine HL group so that we can restore it when we are done searching
    if (g:firstCall)
        let g:originalStatusLineHLGroup = execute("hi StatusLine")
        let g:firstCall = 0
    endif

    if (exists("g:searching") && g:searching)
        " The variable g:searching is set to 1, we are in the search command line
        " make the highlighting and call the function again after a delay
        let searchString = escape(getcmdline(), ' \')
        let newBG = search(searchString) != 0 ? "green" : "red"
        execute("hi StatusLine ctermbg=" . newBG)
        let g:highlightTimer = timer_start(300, 'HighlightSearch')
    else
        " The variable g:searching is either not set or set to 0, we stopped searching
        " restore the hightlighting and stop calling the function
        let originalBG = matchstr(g:originalStatusLineHLGroup, 'ctermbg=\zs[^ ]\+')
        execute("hi StatusLine ctermbg=" . originalBG)

        if exists("g:highlightTimer")
            call timer_stop(g:highlightTimer)
        endif
    endif
endfunction

" Define an autocmd to call the HighLightSearch function when we enter the search command line
" And a second one to stop the function when we are done searching
augroup betterSeachHighlighting
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineEnter * if (index(['?', '/'], getcmdtype()) >= 0) | let g:searching = 1 | let g:firstCall = 1 | call timer_start(1, 'HighlightSearch') | endif
    autocmd CmdlineLeave * let g:searching = 0
augroup END
```

The idea is to create two autocommands:

- The first one is triggered when you enter the command line, it test if you are searching for something (`/` or `?` in opposition to `:`), it sets two variables used by the function and call the function.
- The second one is triggered when you leave the command line, it is used to unset a variable which is used by the function.

The function does three things:

- It keeps in memory the original highlighting group of the status line to be able to restore it (Using [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12294/1841)).
- If you are searching for something it looks for a match, updates the background of the status line accordingly and set a timer to call itself again a few milliseconds later to update the background again.
- If you are not searching for something anymore it resets the status line highlighting.

Here are some relevant help topic (I'll try to upload a gif of the code in action when I can):

- [`:h :highlight`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3ahighlight)
- [`:h getcmdline()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcmdline%28%29)
- [`:h search()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#search%28%29)
- [`:h timer_start()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#timer_start%28%29)
- [`:h timer_stop()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#timer_stop%28%29)
- [`:h CmdlineEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CmdlineEnter)
- [`:h CmdlineLeave`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CmdlineLeave)
- [`:h getcmdtype()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getcmdtype%28%29)

Comment: sorry for not being able to fix this myself, but now I get `Error detected while processing function HighlightSearch:
line   19:
E417: missing argument: ctermbg=`

Comment: @Bananach Oh that might be a problem. Actually it is (probably) because you don't have a `ctermbg` defined in you highlighting group `StatusLine`. If you are using gVim, you can try to replace every occurences of `ctermbg` with `guibg`. Otherwise could you quit vim, restart it and give the output of `:hi StatusLine`?

Comment: Thanks figured it out, added `hi StatusLine ctermbg=white ctermfg=black`. Works nicely.

Comment: Since I normally don't use a statusline, I just tried to add `set laststatus=2` and `set laststatus=1` in the parts of your function corresponding to entering and leaving search mode. This gives the strangest behavior: vim then cycles automatically and perpetually through all the matches of the current search string, and with an empty search string it cycles through the matches of `set laststatus=`

Comment: I fixed this by wrapping the set command in `if (&laststatus!=2)` statements

Comment: Actually `set laststatus=X` should be done only once in your vimrc, I'm not sure it is a good idea to set and unset it dynamically in the code

Comment: Why? Works nicely for me so far

Comment: (btw you mean `laststatus`, right?)

Comment: @Bananach Yup `laststatus` sorry :) (I edited my previous comment to avoid confusion for future users)