# Getting an RGB color from highlight group

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, color, neovim-python-client

In putting together and addon for blender to integrate `neovim`.

[image]
*Where I'm at with it, github colo imported to blender text editor from nvim_gtk*

One component is grabbing the current colorscheme of a running vim and importing it into blender's text editor theme.

So far I have some `re` code that looks at the return of `hi` and follows links if need be  till I get a guifg or guibg

```
# vim is a pynvim.api.nvim.Nvim object
vim_color = vim.command_output(f"highlight {g}")
```

which for `g = "pythonBuiltin"` returns

```
pythonBuiltin xxx links to GruvboxOrange
```

and so on

```
GruvboxOrange xxx ctermfg=208 guifg=#fe8019
```

in which case I can get the RGB colour for blender from the hex.  Other colour codes not so easy.  And the code is getting unwieldly.

Could you point me to a more direct way, possibly a plugin,  to get the RGB value of a highlight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the [`synIDattr()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#synIDattr%28%29) function, which can take special attributes such as `fg#` and `bg#` to return RGB for attributes, when a GUI is running.

```
"fg#"   like "fg", but for the GUI and the GUI
        is running the name in "#RRGGBB" form
"bg#"   like "fg#" for "bg"
"sp#"   like "fg#" for "sp"
```

The first argument to this function is a numeric `{synID}`, if you have a file styled with syntax elements you can look up the id from a specific position in the file.

If you want to find all syntax groups, then perhaps you could iterate them starting from 1 and looking up the name with `synIDattr(..., 'name')` to build a full map from name to RGB attributes.

For instance, to get the RGB for the foreground color of `pythonComment`, you can use the following command:

```
echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID("pythonComment")), "fg#")
```

Comment: You bloody beauty.  I had begun recreating the wheel. So easy to find when you know where to look,... the answers pop strait from the docs `:echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("."), 1)), "fg#")`  Thankyou that works like a treat!!!

Comment: I'm glad this helped! I happened to be in fact looking at something similar earlier this week (debugging syntax, so looking at how to see highlight group for a position) so I stared at these docs for a while. Good luck with your blender integration!

Comment: This has got it `echo  synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID("pythonComment")), "fg#")`

Comment: I didn't know about `hlID()`, so glad I learned it from this question, thanks for that! Incorporated it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any plugins for this but it should be easy to code up lookup tables for the other codes.

The decimal numbers, like 208 in your example, are 256-color palette codes. It's easy to find translations to/from hex code. Like the top of the google search for [256 color to hex](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors).

The spelled-out colors (e.g. DarkSeaGreen4) are system dependent. You didn't mention what system you're using, I don't think. But for *nix that same translation page includes spelled colors, too.. For windows start with `:h win32-colors` and go from there.

Comment: On Ubuntu. Thanks. I was afraid it would come down to LUTs. ... so I'm going to be slow about accepting that fate lol.  Find using  `matplotlib.colors` methods covers most named colors  [eg these](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/View_all_colors_available_to_gvim)  but will need to delve into what, for example  LUT 4 represents . Was hoping there may be some sneaky way to get a rgb from a "live" hightlight.